# jquery dont work on my plugin wordpress when user logged in, but work very well when user or admin not logged in

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i am currently working with jquery and wordpress plugin.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.btn').click(function(){
          alert("hello world");
    });
});
```

this code working very well when run on the site as a usual visitor, but it is refuse to work when i am logged in on that wordpress site.

is there anything wrong in my code that could possibly make this problem happen?

any help would be very appreciated.
thanks in advance..

EDIT : 
after try to open my consol, i try to enter my code above and run it via console. and then try to click the button again, the code working.
i dont understand why.
since my js file is there, included by the

that mean --if i'm not wrong -- my code is there, but the function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    ......
});
```

not executed when document is ready.
that is why when i try to run it via console. the program run just like when i am not logged in.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this code.

Comment: Maybe a different template is loaded when you've logged-in, and it's not including the jQuery library.

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in the console?

Comment: i see the source of the page and the jquery is loaded.

Comment: @ahb > i don't see any error message in consol, or i just dont know how or where to put the code to write to the consol log, and i think it will not work if i put it after the $('.btn').click..... line. below or above the alert("hello world"); line since the alert script doesnt even executed.

if somebody could lead me on how to see or settup the consol log, i would very appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After serveral try and error and also googling and ask and bothering so many people, i finally get change the mothod i used for self execution function. some one said `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})` will fail somehow (about async or something, i can't remember) so i decide to change `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})` to

```
(function($){
    alert("hello");
})(jQuery);
```

This is work for me.
I write this answer so people that facing the same problem could give it a try..